# wshshell.run can not find file

Tags: vbscript

From a command line I can run

```
oradim.exe -delete -sid DataWare
```

Its in my path so I can do it from any location (I have tested this)

What is failing is

```
oraCMD = "oradim.exe -delete -sid DataWare"
errCMD = wshShell.exec(oraCMD)

if errCMD <> 0 Then
    msgbox "ERROR: " & errCMD
    wscript.quit
end if
```

In this configuration I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". If I use `.run` instead of `.exec` I get "The system cannot find the file specified".

Any ideas?

Comment: changing the run command to 

    wshShell.run ("CMD /C oradim.exe -delete -sid Dataware",1,True)

fixed the problem.  But I am not really sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved the problem was calling the CMD in the command line

```
oraCMD = "CMD /c oradim.exe -delete -sid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code mixes .Run (returning a numerical error code) and .Exec (returning an object and needing an assignment with Set). If the process started by WSHShell can't find oradim, then this process didn't get the PATH of the shell you used for testing. How did you start the .vbs? Easy way out: specify full path to oradim.exe.

On second thought: remember to quote the file spec if it contains spaces:

```
oraCMD = """c:\program files\ora labora\oradim.exe"" -delete -sid DataWare"
```

Comment: @Chris: Any spaces in the file spec?

Comment: There are no spaces in the path to the oradim file (E:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin) but it should not be needed since it is part of the path evn variable.  I did try full path (actually thats how I started) but it still had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try     errCMD = wshShell.run(oraCMD)  ?